# How can I perform an action on completion of a knex transaction?

Tags: javascript, transactions, bluebird, knex.js

I have a knex transaction I am performing operations in and passing the transaction reference to other methods, inside those methods I would like to add operations that will happen once the transaction is completed.

For an example with bluebird promises I would like something like this

```
function a () {
  return knex.transaction(function(trx) {
    trx("blah").select().where("fu","bar")
    .then(function(res) {
       b(trx);
    }).then(trx.commit)
    .catch(trx.rollback); 
  }
}

function b(trx) {
  return trx("blah").select().where("fu","bar")
  .then(function(res) {
      // This is where I want to add code to occur after the trx commits
      trx.then(function(){//Do stuff after trx commits})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution was simple I just overlooked it: store the transaction promise and pass that to the inner methods like so:

```
function a () {
  trxPromise = knex.transaction(function(trx) {
    trx("blah").select().where("fu","bar")
    .then(function(res) {
       b(trxPromise,trx);
    }).then(trx.commit)
    .catch(trx.rollback); 
  }
  return trxPromise;
}

function b(trxPromise,trx) {
  return trx("blah").select().where("fu","bar")
  .then(function(res) {
      // This is where I want to add code to occur after the trx commits
      trxPromise.then(function(){//Do stuff after trx commits})
  }
}
```